# Xcopy wont work when path has Brackets like () in Directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

Xcopy wont work when path has Brackets like () in Directory any workaround?

`SET ProgFiles_86=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
SET Program_name_64=%ProgramFiles%\Path\Program name (64 Bit)\File.dll
SET Program_name_32=%ProgramFiles%\Path\Program_name\File.dll
::SET Program_name_86=%ProgFiles_86%\Path\Program_name\File.dll`

`IF NOT EXIST  "%Program_name_64%" (echo Skipping %Program_Dir_86% -- NO DIR) 
ELSE (xcopy /t /U /r /h /l /f /i /s /y "64bit.DLL" "%ProgramFiles%\Path\Program_name (64)\64bit.DLL")`

I even tried

`:ProgFiles64Root
IF NOT "%Program_name_64%"=="" echo Skipping %Program_name_64% -- NO DIR
IF NOT "%Program_name_64%"=="" GOTO ProgFilesRoot 
xcopy /t /U /r /h /l /f /i /s /y "64bit\amtlib.dll" "%ProgramFiles%\Path\Program name (64 Bit)\File.dll"
:ProgFilesRoot
IF NOT "%Program_name_32%"=="" echo Skipping %Program_name_32% -- NO DIR
IF NOT "%Program_name_32%"=="" GOTO ProgFiles_86Root 
xcopy /t /U /r /h /l /f /i /s /y "32bit\amtlib.dll" "%ProgramFiles%\Path\Program_name\File.dll"
:ProgFiles_86Root
IF NOT "%Program_name_86%"=="" echo Skipping %Program_name_86% -- NO DIR
IF NOT "%Program_name_86%"=="" GOTO notProgFiles86Root 
xcopy /t /U /r /h /l /f /i /s /y "32bit\amtlib.dll" "%ProgFiles_86%\Path\Program_name (86 Bit)\File.dll"
:notProgFiles86Root`

I tried googling last night and today but nobody has posted this problem all i found was a slochion for  %ProgramFiles(x86)% witch you can see in the Batch and that help's, doing it for the other dir didn't help.

Comment: Escape the brackets with `^`

Comment: So it will be program ^(64 Bit^) like that?

Comment: OK thank you when i did the echo it work's . However when i did this If Not Exist  "%Program_name%" (xcopy /t /U /r /h /l /f /i /s /y "64bit\amtlib.dll" "%ProgramFiles%\name ^(64^)\amtlib.dll") else ( echo Skipping %adobe_PF_PSCS5_64% -- NO DIR)      It didn't work. The Batch closed with on  error.

Comment: Update! after playing around it worked thanks i appreciate it. This is solved.